# Error in BASIC: expected '='

Tags: user-defined-functions, basic

I received the error "ERROR: expected '='" while trying to compile my code. I'm guessing it has something to do with my function definition. Can anyone help?

```
1  REM declare function
2  DEF FNS(a) = a * a
3
4  REM declare variables
5  LET numOne = 0.0
6  LET answer = 0.0
7
8  REM get input from user
9  INPUT "Enter a number: "; numOne
10
11 REM get answer
12 answer = FNS(numOne)
13
14 REM display answer
15 PRINT "Answer: "; FNS(numOne)
```

Comment: Perhaps if you spell it the same in both the def and the call :)

Comment: Could you include the variant of basic in the question?

Comment: Not related to your problem: you should be in the habit of numbering your statements with gaps, such as by 10 instead of by one (10, 20, 30,...). That way, if you need to insert some code, you don't have to renumber everything.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Sorry. I fixed that after I posted. Still getting the error.

Comment: @HSchmale I am currently using an iPhone app to compile it. It doesn't state the variant. I'll do some looking though. I think it may be Dartmouth.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Didn't the interpreter give you a line number with the error message?

Comment: @lurker No it did not

Comment: @Paulo may have caught it: use `,` instead of `;` in your `INPUT` statement.

Comment: Try changing it, and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' help. I was just trying out classic Basic since I use VB all the time

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: @Paulo No, not yet. I have a Chipmunk Basic compiler at home that I'm going to try. Everything looks ok as far as I can see.

Comment: The variant is JS Basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work perfectly on many BASIC variants (e.g. AppleSoft - see [this emulator](http://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/http://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/)), but not on every one.

If by JS Basic you mean [this project](http://jsbasic.apphb.com/default.aspx), then realize that this variant has (as far as I know) no support for `DEF FN`, so you will have to do with `GOSUB`. Also, the arguments to `PRINT` and `INPUT` are sepparated by a simple whitespace (not semi-colon) and it is mandatory to append `$` to each variable name.

I tweaked your code to work within those constraints (it runs alright in the JS Basic link above). I kept your line numbers multiplied by 10 to ease comparison.

```
00  GOTO 35
05
10  REM Subroutine SQUARE
15  REM Input: arg$ Output: result$
20  result$ = arg$ * arg$
25  RETURN
30
35  REM Program Start
40  REM declare variables
50  numOne$ = 0.0
60  answer$ = 0.0
70
80  REM get input from user
90  INPUT "Enter a number: " numOne$
100
110 REM get answer by calling SQUARE subroutine
112 arg$ = numOne$
115 GOSUB 10
120 answer$ = result$
130
140 REM display answer
150 PRINT "Answer: " answer$
```

Notice that in this variant you don't have to initialize your variables before using e.g. with `INPUT`, so you don't really need lines 50 and 60.